# Wide Range Input (Sinking/Sourcing) to Arduino

Tags: opto-isolator

Figure 1: I am trying to create a circuit that will take a 24 to 3 v digital signal that I can connect to an arduino input. I'd like to have an indicator in the circuit to show that the signal is present. I started selecting smd components but I'm stuck on getting the resistors and current values worked out. I need to use a bidirectional opto-isolater so that I can connect a sinking or sourcing device to this circuit. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

[image: Optocoupler]

```
                                        Figure 1
```

**UPDATED:** Figure 2: Arduino Input has been changed to provide a 5v signal when the field input is conducting and 0v when the field input is not conducting. Field Input will either be NPN or PNP (0v on "DigitalFieldInput" or 24v on "DigitalFieldInput"). I've designed another circuit that will dump the excessive voltage and bring it down to a manageable level. I'm still not sure my resistor values are correct.
It still doesn't look right. For PNP, I would connect 24v to the "digitalfieldinput" and 0v to "common" and the circuit should work, however for NPN, I would connect 24v to "common" and the 0v signal would be connected to "digitalfieldinput". In the NPN connection, there would be no current limiting because 24v would go through the leds/opto-coupler and then through the BATS54S directly to ground. I think I closer with this circuit but still not usable. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
                                          Figure 2
```

**UPDATED**: Figure 3: Field input to be 3-30vdc. Another kick at the can. After thinking about it longer, I decided to try using a double zener to offload the excessive voltage down to 5.1v. I used a 500ohm resister to limit the current of the circuit to 50ma. 20ma through the opto, 20ma through the visible LED and 10 through the zener. The only thing I don't like about this circuit is the size of the 500 ohm resister needs to be at least 1.5W.

Am I on the right track?

[image]

```
                                        Figure 3
```

Comment: 3V to 24V is a very wide range input, you may end up overdriving the LED at the high side or underdriving it on the low side. I've designed a similar circuit that works down to about 12V and up to 32V, but not as low as 3V. [See this question that I asked for the diagram](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334188/confusion-about-what-should-be-a-simple-resistor-divider-circuit)

Comment: I have not got the time at the moment but I think you need to add an active element. E.g. a transistor which limits (bypasses?) the LED current resistor at higher voltages but is passive at lower voltages. It would help if you tell at what speed this is suppose to switch.

Comment: @jonfarr, Design for \$3\:\text{V}\$ and make provisions for disposing of the excess voltage. When you say "sinking or sourcing" do you mean the NPN vs PNP type outputs that some 3-wire sensor devices have?

Comment: Updated Original Post

Comment: @jonk, Something like figure 3?

Comment: @Oldfart Any suggestions?

Comment: I was thinking of using a depletion FET as they are normally ON when there is not voltage. When the voltage rises, use that voltage to pinch of the current. This is all based on theoretical ideas, I have no practical experience with this. Googling "constant current depletion fet schematic" Gave [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Application_Note_Applications_for_Depletion_MOSFETs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624cb7f111014cd63d1a197d94) link which looks promising.